# Convert string to python date type object with timezone offset using strptime

Tags: python, datetime, strptime

What is the correct format to convert this string `Tue Jan 10 2017 13:00:13 GMT 0800 (Taipei Standard Time)` to a python date type object using `strptime`?

I tried the answer from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime) and it is not working for me:

```
date1 = datetime.strptime(strDate1, '%b %d %Y %I:%M%p')
```

> ValueError: time data 'Tue Jan 10 2017 13:00:13 GMT 0800 (Taipei
>   Standard Time)' does not match format '%b %d %Y %I:%M%p'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nominally you would want to be able to use the %z (lowercase z) to convert the TZ offset, however support for this is sketchy. So you can DIY it:

```
import datetime as dt
import re
PARSE_TIMESTAMP = re.compile('(.*) ([+-]?\d+) \(.*\)$')


def my_datetime_parse(timestamp):
    ''' return a naive datetime relative to UTC '''

    # find the standard time stamp, and the TZ offset and remove extra end
    matches = PARSE_TIMESTAMP.match(timestamp).groups()

    # convert the timestamp element
    timestamp = dt.datetime.strptime(matches[0], '%a %b %d %Y %H:%M:%S %Z')

    # calculate the timezone offset
    tz_offset = matches[1]
    sign = '+'
    if tz_offset[0] in '-+':
        sign = tz_offset[0]
        tz_offset = tz_offset[1:]
    tz_offset += '0' * (4 - len(tz_offset))
    minutes = int(tz_offset[0:2]) * 60 + int(tz_offset[2:])
    if sign == '-':
        minutes = -minutes

    # add the timezone offset to our time
    timestamp += dt.timedelta(minutes=minutes)
    return timestamp

date_string = 'Tue Jan 10 2017 13:00:13 GMT +0800 (Taipei Standard Time)'
print(my_datetime_parse(date_string))
```

This code produces:

```
2017-01-10 21:00:13
```

The code removes the `(Taipei Standard Time)` since it is redundant with the `+0800`.

Comment: this will works with dynamic datetime string format?

Comment: This code assumes that there is a parenthesized field with `(extranaous stuff)` at the end that needs to be removed.  It also assumes that there is a timezone offset that needs to be parsed.  This could be done with the %z format if it were better supported.

Answer (score 2):

You can format the date without timezone and add it later,

```
 import pytz

 date1=datetime.strptime('Tue Jan 10 2017 13:00:13', '%a %b %d %Y %H:%M:%S')
 tz=pytz.timezone('Asia/Taipei')
 tz.localize(date1)
```

Comment: im trying to remove the timezone since the string is a javascript `new Date()` object

Comment: I am not sure I got you correctly, do you want something like this `datetime.strptime(strDate1[:24], format)`?

Comment: slicing the string wont go bad? is suppose the length of that string may change?

Comment: i'll try this one

Comment: If you want to try split instead of slicing, you can give a try on this `' '.join(strDate1.split()[:5])`